# how this works:while (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b), (a || b))

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

My question is that in the below program,how  does the code

```
while (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b), (a || b))
```

is being evaluated?

The program get two number and print the sum:

```
int a, b; 
while (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b), (a || b))
    printf("%d\n", a + b);
```

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, so please tag your question correctly

Comment: The `a || b` is the loop control, but the program fails to make the essential check of the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: Yes , I know C and C++ are different languages but the Question I asked is common to both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program has a logical error - entering fewer than two numbers and closing the stream would make the program go into an infinite loop. If you close the stream on the first iteration, you would also get undefined behavior, because `a` or `b` will be read before writing.

The reason for this is that [comma `,` operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) discards the result of evaluating its first operand:

```
while (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b), (a || b))
```

will call `scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)`, and proceed to evaluating `a || b` regardless of the outcome. This is incorrect, because `scanf` may return an indication that the stream has ended prior to reading two integers.

A better way to writing this program is as follows:

```
while ((scanf("%d %d", &a, &b) == 2) && (a || b))
```

This is also more intuitive, because `&&` stands out better than comma.

**Note:** `a || b` means the same thing as `a != 0 || b != 0`, i.e. that at least one of `a` or `b` is non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

Read more documentation about [C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and its [standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library).

Start by reading *carefully* the documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Then read about the [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) `,` and the [logical operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_logical) (e.g. `||` and `&&`)

Also, compile your code with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and run it step by step in the debugger (`gdb`). That would give you some (partial) intuition about how your computer is running your code.

Don't forget to read about [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), notably C.Lattner's blog: [What every C programmer should know about undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

A better code might be:

```
int a, b; 
while ((a=b=0), (scanf("%d %d", &a, &b)==2) && (a || b))
   printf("%d\n", a + b);
```

Answer (score 0):

how it runs:
if user enters two integers it will print sum of these two integers,
and ask for two next input until user enters two zero integers,
and if user enters not integer value like `aaa` it will prints previous `a+b` value and **loops for ever without asking new input**!

so that is **bad code**:

1. try to write as simple as possible(there is no point in combining C statements)
2. always check for errors
3. use system independent types like `int32_t` from `#include<stdint.h>` when needed
4. initialize variables

my recommended sample:

```
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int32_t a, b;
    do{
        if (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) != 2) {
            printf("incorrect  input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n", a, b, a + b);

    } while (a || b);
    return 0;
}
```

terminal output(+input):

```
10
20
10 + 20 = 30
0
0
0 + 0 = 0
```